# How to stop "Java platform SE binary" using excessive CPU

Tags: java, eclipse

Suddenly, even after weeks of normal use, **Java(TM) Platform SE binary** has started using excessive CPU, causing intense lag on my PC.

The lag starts when I run any program in Java Eclipse Photon. The program is incredibly basic, it should literally just print `"hello"`, but it takes `10` seconds of `70%` CPU usage to do it.

It has worked previously, but I don't know what has changed.

My Specs are :

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70Ghz 2.40Ghz
6.00GB Installed memory
64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
```

It may be relevant that there are multiple of these `Java` Platform `SE` Binary programs open, sometimes up to three, but only one will be using excessive CPU, the others will use about `3%` each.

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Edit: Simple programs were working quickly previously, but now they are very intensive for seemingly no reason. I have restarted everything, and have the latest version of Java.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse uses a lot of CPU, not your program

Comment: are you getting the same issue when running them outside the IDE as JARs?

Comment: *How to stop “Java platform SE binary” using excessive CPU*  **Stop resource leaking in your applications**

Comment: @Antoniossss there is probably no leak in a 1 line app with a single console print

Comment: @jhamon I don't follow pasted links.

Comment: What do you mean by latest Java version? Java 8 (LTS), Java 10 (non-LTS) or Java 11 (EA)? To which applications belong the two Java processes? Eclipse and your "Hello World" application? Are background jobs/tasks running in Eclipse (_Window > Show View > Progress_)?

Answer (score -1):

Click right mouse button on this process, choose 'preferences' and check path what exactly it is. My bet it's an eclipse, not your app. To verify this export app, close eclipse, run app by typing `java -jar YourJarName.jar` and then check results in Task Manager